# App's function running on emulator, but not running on real device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm setting up camera app. There are functions like "capture" "rotate camera"  "gallery"   "back" etc. Application is running on emulator include all functions, but on real device, "capture" and "rotate camera" not working.

I have already tried the Instant Run - Clean & Rebuild App

MainActivity

```
camera.captureImage { camera, capturedImage ->
            val savedPhoto = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "photo.jpg")
            try {
                val outputStream = FileOutputStream(savedPhoto.path)
                outputStream.write(capturedImage)
                outputStream.close()
            } catch (e: java.io.IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            //capturedImage converted to bitmap
            var bitmap: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(capturedImage, 0, capturedImage.size)
            capturedImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            capturedImageView.visibility=View.VISIBLE
```

I expect the applications all functions run in both emulator and real device which is General Mobile 5 Plus

Comment: Do you get any errors, crashes, log messages?

Comment: only this : Access denied finding property "persist.camera.cfa.packagelist"

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using Camera2 and not just Camera. And provide below permissions too when using Camera2.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.autofocus" />
```

Comment: Is it that particular device which is not working, or few others too?

Comment: at the beginning it was working on  my real device to , but after the restart the Android Studio , not work again.  What might be caused something like that ? Because of xml , manifest or  .gradle ? I have been searching almost for 3 hours

Comment: Kindly, 
- Uninstall the app and re-install it (try rebooting the device)
- Download the project from the link and if it works, let me know further (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)

Comment: I have tested with another real device (samsung a7)  and worked fine

Comment: See, that's what I told you, might have been that issue, well congrats.